# What database and setup can handle several million inserts per minute?

Tags: performance, performance-tuning, data-warehouse, nosql, cassandra

We have come to a point where for a few of our customers' systems, at peak times, events are generated at that crazy rate. That is, millions of new events per minute (between 1M and 2M).

The records/docs size are 1.5Kb on average.

Is there a database that can handle such radical write speed out there (16K - 32k inserts per second)?

There are several candidates out there, Cassandra, Hive, Hadoop, HBase, Riak and perhaps a few others, but I would like to know from someone else's *experience* and not just quoting from each database system's website self testimonials.

If you have handled such load at your work, your advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Think about how banks handle billions of consistent transactions. Through sharding and batch processing you can handle any number of transactions, it is just a case of using the right structure rather than throwing hardware at the wrong structure.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, let me start simple: My old trusted 5 year old main db server (2x quad core AMD Opteron 2378) handles around 80,000 inserts per second, though small ones. That is without SSD for log and data on a SQL Server.

There are plenty of databases that can meet your requirement - it is MOSTLY a question of appropriate hardware. Heck, if you would go Oracle, then the smallest Exadata in a performance configuration (pure SSD) likely can do 10 times as much - we got in a project 5 gigabyte/second stable IO out of it, with a paltry 3 storage nodes.

That said, you WILL have to test it yourself. A lot depends on your programming or lack thereof. If you hit 1 insert per transaction, that is VERY different - and a lot harder to do (not at all because your log partitions need to handle 5 million IOPS then or fake the flush).